# How to get AWS Account name from AWS_ACCESS_KEY and AWS_SECRET_KEY

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud, openstack

I am managing several AWS accounts on behalf of clients, usually I set `AWS_ACCESSKEY_KEY` and `AWS_SECRET_KEY` environment variables to run my shell scripts to perform routine operations. Now before executing script I would like to fetch the AWS Account name on the basis of `AWS_ACCESS_KEY` and `AWS_SECRET_KEY` environment variable to be sure against which account it will be fired! So how to get using commands from shell prompt or in shell script ?

Comment: Try [get-user](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/get-user.html)

Comment: ...remembering, of course, that this means you're arguably generating unnecessary and potentially billable API calls to AWS against your clients' accounts, given enough volume.  Keeping local records when keys are provided might be a better approach.

Comment: Rajesh Thanks for your reply! but to use `get-user` we have to pass user name as a string, Right!. But what if I only have `AWS_ACCESS_KEY` and `AWS_SECRET_KEY`? Is it possible to get first user name based on that and then get the AWS Account name. My main purpose is on the basis of `AWS_SECRET_KEY` `AWS_ACCESSKEY` shell script must identify AWS account and confirm the same with Y/N, when shell AWS reporting and management shell script is being fired.

Comment: Michael! thanks for your reply! As I am firing shell scripts against AWS accounts - firing many API calls to AWS account. In that executing one or two to determine account name would be must effected. Yes you are right keeping local accounts is best way, but when shell script fires I want to display AWS account name on the screen and then getting (Y/N) confirmation from user to execute the shell script.